# Prevent pydub from creating temporary files when playing and processing audio?

Tags: pydub

Here's my code. The function is often called with the same file name to play. Each call creates several temporary files. How to avoid this? or create one temporary file for each call with the same name?

```
def play_sound(file_name):    
    path_file=os.path.join(WAV_FLDR, file_name)
    path_file+= ".ogg"    
    if os.path.exists(path_file): 
        ogg_audio = AudioSegment.from_ogg(path_file)
        sound =ogg_audio.apply_gain(-ogg_audio.max_dBFS)
        silence_threshold = -45
        
        nonsilent_ranges=silence.split_on_silence(sound,silence_thresh=silence_threshold,min_silence_len=80)
        cnt=0
        for sound in nonsilent_ranges:
            cnt+=1
            play(sound)
    else:
        print(f"File didnt finder {path_file}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a virtual environment.
If you have installed PyDub globally then make sure to navigate where the packages are installed on your operating system.

Image Link: [Pydub Temporary File Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPG4F.png)

Open `path/to/packages/pydub/playback.py` and in the function `_play_with_ffplay(seg)`, make the following change:

From: `with NamedTemporaryFile("w+b", suffix=".wav") as f:`

To: `with NamedTemporaryFile("w+b", suffix=".wav", delete=True) as f:`

It stops creating the temporary files multiple times for each call.